# Get path to certain folder in python

Tags: python, directory

I need to get the location of the startup folder, like so: on my computer it looks like this:

```
C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup
```

but how do I get the path to this folder on any computer using Python?

I'm trying to use the function `shutil.copy2()` replacing the A below with the path to startup

```
shutil.copy2("C:\\Users\\NAME_OF_USER\\Downloads\\file.exe", "A")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the `USERPROFILE` environment variable in Windows to get the path to the current user's directory

```py
import os

a = os.path.normpath(os.path.expandvars('$USERPROFILE') + 'AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup')
shutil.copy2("C:\\Users\\NAME_OF_USER\\Downloads\\file.exe", a)
```